# URL rewrite problems

Tags: php

I am working on www.quippoauctions.com site here I am facing one problem. I have a

url: `http://www.quippoauctions.com/index.php?do=auctiondetails&id=1134`

i want to show this url as

```
http://www.quippoauctions.com/auctiondetails/1134/demo_auction_for_training_purpose.html
```

with the help of .htaccess file acn anyone help me on this

I have an htaccess file where I am writing

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^auctiondetails/(.*)/(.*).html$ ?do=auctiondetails&id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/demo_auction_for_training_purpose\.html$ /index.php?do=$1&id=$2
```

**OR**

```
RewriteRule ^auctiondetails/1134/demo_auction_for_training_purpose.html$ index.php?do=auctiondetails&id=1134 [L]
```

Comment: i have try this but not working it will give 404 Not Found error